# I get “Error: Deploy failed: b''” when deploying to Scrapy Cloud

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to deploy some spiders on Scrapy Cloud, I am getting this message at the end:

```
Error: Deploy failed: b''
```

The spiders appear in the dashboard but don't run (doesn't even start to run).
I have this in requirements.txt:

```
bs4==0.0.1
boto==2.49.0
```

And this is what scrapinghub.yml:

```
project: <my project ID>
stacks:
    default: scrapy:1.7-py3
requirements:
   file: requirements.txt
```

Comment: `Error: Deploy failed: b''` looks weird, that byte string should contain the error response from the server. You should contact support.

Comment: @Gallaecio Thanks, It was a server problem on their side. it is fixed now